How to swap tokens on Neutron chain using cosmpy library?
I have been struggling to automate the process of swapping tokens on Neutron chain, but haven't got any luck so far. For ease of understanding, I want to swap from NTRN to ASTRO. I know there's a python library cosmpy that can handle this but I don't know where to start. I have tried to implement their documentation for Fetch network but for some reasons it's not working for Neutron. I can connect to the network and fetch token balances using the following script.
from cosmpy.aerial.client import LedgerClient, NetworkConfig

cfg = NetworkConfig(
    chain_id="neutron-1",
    url="grpc+https://neutron-grpc.publicnode.com:443",
    fee_denomination="untrn",
    staking_denomination="untrn",
    fee_minimum_gas_price=0.0053,
)

ledger = LedgerClient(cfg=cfg)
balances = ledger.query_bank_all_balances('neutron1xfe27dm62f8lmdtcmltcyxaw6knsa9llcuz7ar')

I'd appreciate if someone could help with the process of swapping tokens. Thanks!
